# Assigning Session variable from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session

Hi all I am assigning a `Session` variable using Javascript as follows, I am using `devexpress` controls

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function f() {
        var v = textBox1.GetValue();
        <%Session["Demo"] = v;%>
        var sValue='<%=Session["Demo"]%>';
        textBox3.SetValue(sValue);
    }
</script>
```

This is giving an error on webpage when I run as `The name 'v' does not exist in the current context`

So can some one help me what to do

Comment: Cannot be done , JS executes in client side .

Answer (score 2):

As @The New Idiot mentioned - it cannot be done on a client side, since Session objects are stored on a server side. The only way you can do it is on some request `get/post` or even ajax request and set variable on a server side